# Calculating power of brain signals

Tags: power-spectral-density, time-frequency, amplitude, time-series, array-signal-processing

I have a dataset that contains EEG (or MEG) recordings of brain signals during some cognitive tasks.

Each row, shows the source estimates of neurons in a particular region.
source estimate contains the time series of a activations at spatial locations defined by the source space.

So basically, I have the "time series of a activations at spatial locations defined by the source space" in each row of my data.

I have to calculate the power (amplitude?) of each of these time-series data. How should I do that?

Comment: It's not clear what "power" is in this context; you're the expert for neurology, you'll have to help us here – we can't tell you how power relates to your observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power of a 1D signal is defined as time-average of energy:

$$
P_x = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} |x[n]|^2
$$

This can be applied on each channel independently.

However, there are many other measures of "power of brain signals" - depending on the exact physical source we seek to describe. In particular, EEG describes *electrical* sources, and MEG magnetic, and the two differ in localization, noise due to measurement device interaction with patient, etc.

One approach is to compute the [surface Laplacian](http://userwww.sfsu.edu/barros/publications/publications/files/CarvalhaesdeBarros2015.pdf), which relates potentials directly to physical sources. I recommend [Analyzing Neural Time Series Data](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262019876) for further reading.